# Hi , I have error related to object detection project

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I have  error related to simple object detection .

> output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

```py
import cv2.cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load Yolo

net = cv.dnn.readNet('yolov3.weights','yolov3.cfg')
classes = []
with open ("coco.names","r") as f:
 classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
otputlayers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

 #Loading image

 img = cv.imread("room_ser.jpg")

cv.imshow("Image",img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The reason is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834335/loading-yolo-invalid-index-to-scalar-variable/69881065

Answer (score 20):

`getUnconnectedOutLayers()` returns an integer, not an iterable. Instead, use

```py
outputlayers = [layer_names[i-1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

The examples shown [here](https://codesuche.com/python-examples/cv2.dnn.readNet/) are incorrect. More information on the method can be found on the [cv2 docs here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/db/d30/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1Net.html#ae62a73984f62c49fd3e8e689405b056a).

The error itself (`IndexError`) tells you that you are trying to index something that is a scalar.

Comment: It's best just to let people upvote material organically. If you want to get to the 50 mark, try to write one good answer per day for a week, and by the end of the week you should be there. Rep is fun, but don't make it the sole reason you are here - satisfaction can be had in helping people.

Answer (score 0):

That index issue because it can not iterate

```
unconnected_indices = neural_network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()
output_names = [layer_names[index - 1] for index in unconnected_indice

bounding_box = all_bounding_boxes[index]

if class_ids[index] == 0:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    class_with_confidence = 'PERSON' + str(int(confidence_values[index] * 100)) + '%'
    cv2.putText(img, class_with_confidence, (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1)
```

Comment: Can you post traceback?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34896903)