# Loading YOLO: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, yolo

Getting an error for IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable on the yolo_layers line.

```
network = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3.cfg', 'yolov3.weights')
layers = network.getLayerNames()
yolo_layers = [layers[i[0] - 1] for i in network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

This code won't work on my Jupyter notebook but will run fine on google collab. No idea why. Could be my python version?

Comment: Please post the full traceback error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's may caused by the different versions of cv2. The version of cv2 module with CUDA support will give you a 2-D array when calling `network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()`. However, the version without CUDA support will give a 1-D array.

You may try to take the brackets out which closing the index 0.

Answer (score 7):

For CPU versions:

```
network = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3.cfg', 'yolov3.weights')
layers = network.getLayerNames()
yolo_layers = [layers[i - 1] for i in network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

returns: `['yolo_82', 'yolo_94', 'yolo_106']`

Tested on OpenCV version `4.5.5`.