# Error while loading Yolov5 custom model using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, yolo, yolov5

I was trying to predict defects on a metal plate using yolov5 pre-trained weights.it was throwing this error:
**
File "C:\Users\acer.spyder-py3\metallic surface defect detection\untitled3.py", line 59, in post_process
if confidence >= CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Constants.
INPUT_WIDTH = 640
INPUT_HEIGHT = 640
SCORE_THRESHOLD = 0.5
NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.45
CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.45

# Text parameters.
FONT_FACE = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
FONT_SCALE = 0.7
THICKNESS = 1

# Colors.
BLACK  = (0,0,0)
BLUE   = (255,178,50)
YELLOW = (0,255,255)

def draw_label(im, label, x, y):
    """Draw text onto image at location."""
    # Get text size.
    text_size = cv2.getTextSize(label, FONT_FACE, FONT_SCALE, THICKNESS)
    dim, baseline = text_size[0], text_size[1]
    # Use text size to create a BLACK rectangle.
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x,y), (x + dim[0], y + dim[1] + baseline), (0,0,0), cv2.FILLED);
    # Display text inside the rectangle.
    cv2.putText(im, label, (x, y + dim[1]), FONT_FACE, FONT_SCALE, YELLOW, THICKNESS, cv2.LINE_AA)
    
def pre_process(input_image, net):
      # Create a 4D blob from a frame.
      blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(input_image, 1/255,  (INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False)

      # Sets the input to the network.
      net.setInput(blob)

      # Run the forward pass to get output of the output layers.
      outputs = net.forward(net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames())
      return outputs
  
def post_process(input_image, outputs):
      # Lists to hold respective values while unwrapping.
      class_ids = []
      confidences = []
      boxes = []

      # Rows.
      rows = outputs[0].shape[1]
      image_height, image_width = input_image.shape[:2]
      # Resizing factor.
      x_factor = image_width / INPUT_WIDTH
      y_factor =  image_height / INPUT_HEIGHT
      # Iterate through detections.
      for r in range(rows):
            row = outputs[0][0][r]
            confidence = row[4]
            # Discard bad detections and continue.
            if confidence >= CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD:
                  classes_scores = row[5:]
                  # Get the index of max class score.
                  class_id = np.argmax(classes_scores)
                  #  Continue if the class score is above threshold.
                  if (classes_scores[class_id] > SCORE_THRESHOLD):
                        confidences.append(confidence)
                        class_ids.append(class_id)
                        cx, cy, w, h = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]
                        left = int((cx - w/2) * x_factor)
                        top = int((cy - h/2) * y_factor)
                        width = int(w * x_factor)
                        height = int(h * y_factor)
                        box = np.array([left, top, width, height])
                        boxes.append(box)
                        
 # Perform non maximum suppression to eliminate redundant, overlapping boxes with lower confidences.
      indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)
      for i in indices:
            box = boxes[i]
            left = box[0]
            top = box[1]
            width = box[2]
            height = box[3]             
            # Draw bounding box.             
            cv2.rectangle(input_image, (left, top), (left + width, top + height), BLUE, 3*THICKNESS)
            # Class label.                      
            label = "{}:{:.2f}".format(classes[class_ids[i]], confidences[i])             
            # Draw label.             
            draw_label(input_image, label, left, top)
      return input_image
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
      # Load class names.
      classesFile = "defects.names"
      classes = None
      with open(classesFile, 'rt') as f:
            classes = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')
      # Load image.
      frame = cv2.imread('img_02_3436787300_00007_jpg.rf.e9923d3a70d1aeb92e45896b9c12cfa3.jpg')
      # Give the weight files to the model and load the network using       them.
      modelWeights = "models_train/best.onnx"
      net = cv2.dnn.readNet(modelWeights)
      # Process image.
      detections = pre_process(frame, net)
      img = post_process(frame.copy(), detections)
      """
      Put efficiency information. The function getPerfProfile returns       the overall time for inference(t) 
      and the timings for each of the layers(in layersTimes).
      """
      t, _ = net.getPerfProfile()
      label = 'Inference time: %.2f ms' % (t * 1000.0 /  cv2.getTickFrequency())
      print(label)
      cv2.putText(img, label, (20, 40), FONT_FACE, FONT_SCALE,  (0, 0, 255), THICKNESS, cv2.LINE_AA)
      cv2.imshow('Output', img)
      cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have little bit idea of deploying models into commercial use. If you find any other errors also please inform me . thanks in advance

Comment: You need to debug and check the value in `confidence`. What does it return?

Comment: it was returning a multidimensional array

Comment: That's the problem. You cannot compare an array with a scalar value. You can iterate through the array and compare the confidence level

Comment: @jeru Luke. https://learnopencv.com/object-detection-using-yolov5-and-opencv-dnn-in-c-and-python/

Answer (score 0):

A simple search led me to [this SO post, highlighting a common issue recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834335/loading-yolo-invalid-index-to-scalar-variable).

Following [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv-and-python-21e50ac599e9) got me close but I faced the issue above.

`net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()` returns an array of index values. The output layers are obtained from `net.getLayerNames()` based on these index  values.

In the following case `net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()` returns:

> `array([200, 227, 254])`

We get the output layers from `output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()` which returns:

> `['yolo_82', 'yolo_94', 'yolo_106']`

**Code:**

The following is the complete working code for OpenCV version `4.5.5` (CPU):

```
image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, 'horse.jpg'))
Width = image.shape[1]
Height = image.shape[0]
scale = 0.00392

classes = None
with open(os.path.join(path, 'coco.names'), 'r') as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    
    
COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

net = cv2.dnn.readNet(os.path.join(path, 'yolov3.weights'), os.path.join(path, 'yolov3.cfg'))
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scale, (416,416), (0,0,0), True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)


def get_output_layers(net):
    layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
    output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    return output_layers



def draw_bounding_box(img, class_id, confidence, x, y, x_plus_w, y_plus_h):
    label = str(classes[class_id])
    color = COLORS[class_id]
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x_plus_w,y_plus_h), color, 2)
    img = cv2.putText(img, label, (x-10,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)


# run inference through the network
# and gather predictions from output layers
outs = net.forward(get_output_layers(net))

# initialization
class_ids = []
confidences = []
boxes = []
conf_threshold = 0.5
nms_threshold = 0.4

image2 = image.copy()
for out in outs:
    for detection in out:
        scores = detection[5:]
        class_id = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[class_id]
        if confidence > 0.5:
            center_x = int(detection[0] * Width)
            center_y = int(detection[1] * Height)
            w = int(detection[2] * Width)
            h = int(detection[3] * Height)
            x = center_x - w / 2
            y = center_y - h / 2
            class_ids.append(class_id)
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
    
    # apply non-max suppression
    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, conf_threshold, nms_threshold)
    for i in indices:
       i = i   # i[0]
       box = boxes[i]
       x = box[0]
       y = box[1]
       w = box[2]
       h = box[3]
       draw_bounding_box(image2, class_ids[i], confidences[i], round(x), round(y), round(x+w), round(y+h))
```

**Result:**

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: my weights are in '.pt' format. Is this code work in .pt or .onnx weights?

Comment: I downloaded the `.cfg` file from https://opencv-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/10e685aad953495a95c17bfecd1649e5/yolov3.cfg and `weights` from https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights

Comment: @AbinJilson Hope you solved it

Comment: Here you are using coco dataset's cfg file and weights. I need to run it on my own custom dataset weights which is in '.onnx' and '.pt' format and instead of a '.cfg' file I have a yaml file. It is perfectly working on yolov3 weights and coco dataset. But ,When I try to run on my custom detection model it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to incompatible version of your installed modules.

Download .pt model.

> wget https://github.com/ultralytics/YOLOv5/releases/download/v6.1/YOLOv5s.pt

And export to ONNX using your machine:

> git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/YOLOv5
> cd YOLOv5
> pip install -r requirements.txt
> pip install onnx
> python3 export.py --weights models/YOLOv5s.pt --include onnx

Use the new converted .onnx file can solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).