# invalid index to scalar variable for object detection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, cvlib

I started to work on OpenCV and doing some basic examples. I'm trying to count the objects from image. For example you can see very basic and popular sample in below..

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
from numpy.lib.polynomial import poly

img = cv2.imread('cars.jpg')
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.show()
```

There isn't any problem untill this, but when I try to draw the frames, I'm getting a fault. This code is;

```
box, label, count = cv.detect_common_objects(img)
output = draw_bbox(img, box, label, count)

output = cv2.cvtColor(output,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

It appears a "IndexError" when it run this script..
Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-df69657efc75> in <module>
----> 1 box, label, count = cv.detect_common_objects(img)
      2 output = draw_bbox(img, box, label, count)
      3 
      4 output = cv2.cvtColor(output,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
      5 plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvlib\object_detection.py in detect_common_objects(image, confidence, nms_thresh, model, enable_gpu)
    133     net.setInput(blob)
    134 
--> 135     outs = net.forward(get_output_layers(net))
    136 
    137     class_ids = []

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvlib\object_detection.py in get_output_layers(net)
     27     layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
     28 
---> 29     output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
     30 
     31     return output_layers

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvlib\object_detection.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     27     layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
     28 
---> 29     output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
     30 
     31     return output_layers

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

What do you think could be the problem? by the way, my versions are;

- Python: 3.8.8 (conda env)
- openCV: 4.0.1 (but when check from conda promt with cv2.**version** is 4.5.5.)
- cvlib: 0.2.6

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69756781/hi-i-have-error-related-to-object-detection-project  (imo a bug in cvlib)

Answer (score 0):

The specific location of the image may create that error. I mean the image cant be found. So, try to give the specific location of the image + the image name with its exact extension. ex: "cars.jpg" is different from "cars.jpeg".
Also, the image may be invalid or corrupted. try to check the image separately.
I tried the code you provided and it worked for me.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
from numpy.lib.polynomial import poly

img = cv2.imread('/specific location/cars.jpg')
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.show()
```